# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3> in docker

Tags: docker, gunicorn

This happened when running docker compose up

How do I find the log to see what's the error?

[image]

Comment: Please add some more details in question

Comment: Hi YYY, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, use the built-in code formatting feature instead of images for pieces of code or error messages. This will make it easier for other users to read your question and therefore answer it. Also, you should include the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `guncorn` with `--preload` can see the error log, like this:

```
gunicorn app:application --preload -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this can't work cause I do not have `guncorn` install in my machine, the error is inside the docker container and I don't know how to go in the container to run the command